# Angular 2 template var not updating in ngSwitch

Tags: angular

I have a variable threadCount which gets set via user input and showing the value on the same page.

It works fine for normal interpolation

```
<p>Threads: {{threadCount}}</p>
```

But right below that I am wanting to append it to certain threads (if the name ends in '-').

The following works if I threadCount is defined before the thread is added to selectedThreads

```
  <p>Threads: {{threadCount}}</p>
  <p>Selected LFKs:
    <span *ngFor="let lfk of selectedLFKs; let isLast=last; ">
      <span [ngSwitch]="lfk">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="lfk.charAt(lfk.length -1) === '-'">{{lfk}}{{threadCount}}{{isLast ? '': ', '}}</span>
        <span *ngSwitchDefault>{{lfk}}{{isLast ? '': ', '}}</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>
```

Once the user changes threadCount, the first threadCount interpolation is updated but the one inside of the ngFor and ngSwitch does not.

1. What is the proper way to do this?
2. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After a nice lunch break and some ping pong, I've come to the realization that this should be done in the component.

Instead of using a string array, I made each one an object so that I could add a boolean attribute "threadCount". This way, in my *ngFor I check for the threadCount attribute and appropriately append the thread count number.